# Embed Java applet in a website

Tags: java, html, applet, embed

Recently, I had came across an open source a Java applet.   I wanted to know is there somehow I could create a script that could be distributed and the applet could be embedded in any website?

I have been able to inject JQuery and JS scripts into websites by placing a `<script>` tag pointing to a Javascript file and placing it in the header of the page but I don't know how a java applet can be injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at corresponding tutorial page: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

General steps are the following:

1. Build applet JAR file
2. Create a JNLP file, which describes your applet
3. Create web page, which includes script, which starts applet
4. Deploy all these artifacts on some web server